# How to get all rolegroups in dotnetnuke

Tags: dotnetnuke

RoleController.GetRoleGroups(portalid); is giving only user created group not Global Roles Group that is created by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The global role group is really the absence of a role group.  So, the "global" group is roles with a group ID of `-1`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `RoleController.GetRoleGroups()` for this :-

```
 var arrGroups = RoleController.GetRoleGroups(portalSettings.PortalId);
   foreach (RoleGroupInfo roleGroup in arrGroups)
   {
    //Your Logic goes here :-
   }
```

You can use `RoleController.GetRoles()` for this :-

There are two overload of this method :-

```
 IList<RoleInfo> GetRoles(int portalId, Func<RoleInfo, bool> predicate);

 IList<RoleInfo> GetRoles(int portalId);
```

You can see the [Source code](http://searchco.de/codesearch/view/10045379) here :-

This is how you can use the method :-

```
foreach (var role in TestableRoleController.Instance.GetRoles(portalId))
{
    // you can Put your Logic here :-
}
```